# imap with curl on php

Tags: php, curl, imap

I have created a very simple function:

```
function send($command) {
    $url = 'imaps://myImapServer';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 993);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "MyUsername");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "MyPassword");
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $command);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    return $res;
}
```

I can use it to query folders, but also, for example, the UID of all my messages:

```
echo send('UID SEARCH ALL');
# Output: * SEARCH 63 64 65 66
```

But for two problems I dont find a solution.

- How do I create an array HTML Body, Text Body, Reply to,... from my outputs?
- Why do I get the lenght of the subject with the following query, but the subject itself is not displayed?

  echo send('UID FETCH 63 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]');
  Output: * 1 FETCH (UID 63 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {29}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use a proper IMAP extension, or even any other library - that might be way easier than using raw cURL requests

Comment: In the second sample you see my problem. I don't get the subject. I try to use a proxy. This not work with the imap extension, and Sockets has problem with the proxy and imap. With http request sockets and proxy work fine. So i have take curl. Gives another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $chunk) {
    //your imap handling here
    return strlen($chunk);
});
```

or if you're in a class https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98491

```php
curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, 
            CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 
            array($this, "class_method_name"));
```

CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION keeps listening to your "broken up" input, feeding the chunks it has received in the callback function.

You can use the callback function to concatenate the data, push it all into an array, or just process it as you receive it, depending on what your use case is.